# is it possible to delay fadeIn animation in css

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to delay this fadein animation 5s

```css
.fade-in-image-2 { animation: fadeIn 5s 10s; }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: you are already delaying it 10s

Answer (score 2):

You can set it directly on the CSS property **animation**, or decide to use the rule **animation-delay**.

For example, if we wanna set 2 seconds of delay:

```
animation: 3s linear 2s slidein;
```

or

```
animation-delay: 2s;
```

Here's some docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Answer (score 2):

The [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) property is defined as follows:

```css
animation: animation-name animation-duration animation-timing-function animation-delay animation-iteration-count animation-direction animation-fill-mode animation-play-state;
```

Depending on your code, I guess you want to use `animation-name`, `animation-duration`, and `animation-delay`.

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#element {
  animation: fadeIn 5s 3s; /* animation-name, animation-duration, and animation-delay */
  /* lol, everything down is for illustration purposes only! */
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size:35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="element">Hello!</div>
```